# Неправильное определение разрешение на айфоне

Tags: вёрстка

Есть мобильная версия сайта (полностью резина). 
прописал определение ширины устройства.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

В айфоне 4s разрешение  640 × 960 пикс, а отображает 320 × 480 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

браузеру считать пикселы исходя из размера девайса, а не его реального разрешения. [@media](/users/3055/mediaportal) query правила нужно писать исходя из device pixels, а не реального разрешения.